# Intellij idea - maven settings for new project gets reset when ide restarted

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I changed maven settings for new projects in intellij-idea community edition-2019 from **`File -> Other Settings-> Settings for new projects`** and then under Build Tools -> maven.

[image]

What I changed is
Maven home directory from **`Bundled -> to -> C:\Program Files\Maven`** (install location on my system)
and override settings file **`User settings file -> C:\Program Files\Maven\settings.xml`** <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>Ok</kbd>

Now if I restart ide and revisit maven setting for new project, mentioned as above, it shows original, that comes with intellij-idea(reset to default). How can I make it to save as I changed?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211731 Does it look like your case?

Comment: Yes, that was the bug ,as mentioned in link, upgrading to newer version solved it.

Answer (score 0):

As user Kootli commented in question section, it is bug [filed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211731) for idea 2019.2, Updating to newer version of ide will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the issue still remains. Every time I clone a new repo, these creds get reset and my artifactory user gets locked out because of this issue.

`IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)`